# How to add meta info to mp3/wav file MAC OSX?

Tags: mp3

How to add meta info to mp3/wav file MAC OSX ?
Is there any application?

Comment: Google your question. 3rd answer is a lsit of the best MP3 taggers, including some for Mac OSx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good program for adding meta info to MP3s is Tagr, you can find it at https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30610/tagr
In my opinion it's one of the better ones out there for Mac OSX. I'm not sure of any that will help with WAV files though.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing changes over time, but currently the most common recommendation you'll find is to simply use iTunes due to its ubiquity - import the file, add the data, drag the updated file into a folder.

Answer (score 2):

I've read lots of blogs where people give advice on adding metadata to WAV files.  Most of it doesn't work.  iTunes is useless for adding metadata to WAV or AIFF files, because it only sticks to the file inside iTunes.  If you send the file to a PC or Smart TV the metadata doesn't stick.  Same with VLC player, which I tried as well, it didn't work even though playing the file in VLC player kept the metadata set using VLC player.

Logic Pro X only allows you to add metadata to MP3s, same as Pro Tools.

What worked for me and is free and very easy to use is Audacity.  Just drag your rendered 16 bit 44.1khz  WAV file into Audacity > Edit > Metadata

Then fill in the form with all the metadata you want to include and export the WAV file as a 16 bit WAV file (CD quality). Note: This also works with AIFF files !! But make sure the project settings for Audacity are 16 bits and 44.1khz, otherwise it will resample the audio and you'll get artifacts from that.

You might think that using a free app like Audacity will give you inferior audio quality if you rebounce the original WAV file after adding the metadata, but NO, it is a perfect copy of the original.

I tested this in Protools 11.  Bounced down a mix to a 16 bit 44.1khz WAV file.  Then imported into Audacity, added metadata, and exported as a WAV file with the same parameters.  I then took the original WAV and WAV exported with metadata back into protools, inverted the phase of one of the WAVs and there was perfect cancellation at full volume on my sound system.  So Audacity is pristine, no phase alterations or spectral alterations.

If you want to then turn the WAV file into an MP3, there's lots of ways to do this.  Most DAWs can do this easily and allow you to add metadata for the mp3.  Or you can use the free VLC player > Window > Media Information. Fill in the info and click the "Save Metadata" button.  VLC doesn't render the file again, it just adds the data to it, and it works on computers and smart TVs, you can read the metadata.

How can you tell the metadata stuck?

Look in finder on your Mac if you expand the file window in ‘Column or List’ view you'll see all the metadata in the Finder window when you select the file, same on a PC. Or use ‘Get Info’ on your Mac, and the extra metadata appears under ‘More Information’ in the popup window.

Note: on older OS X the column view on a Mac might not show the metadata, but it will show when you select ‘Get Info’

Smart TVs only see metadata from MP3 files.  So this method will work for computers but not smart TVs, at least not on my one.

By the way: Reaper will add metadata to WAVs as well by using the “Info” scheme when you enter the metadata.  BUT …… it doesn’t seem to work well for AIFF files in version 6.12 of Reaper, maybe it needs fixing …….

Hope that helps.